# Cannot read packageName from D:\projetsPerso\joiedurythme\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have this error on my android project.

> Cannot read packageName from
>   D:\projetsPerso\joiedurythme\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

I can't see where is the problem.

Here is my graddle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {


apply plugin: 'android-library'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    LibraryPlugin plugin = project.plugins.getPlugin(LibraryPlugin)
    JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompile
    javaCompile.doLast {
        String[] args = ["-showWeaveInfo",
                         "-1.5",
                         "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-bootclasspath", plugin.project.android.bootClasspath.join(
                File.pathSeparator)]

        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
        new Main().run(args, handler)

        def log = project.logger
        for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
            switch (message.getKind()) {
                case IMessage.ABORT:
                case IMessage.ERROR:
                case IMessage.FAIL:
                    log.error message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.WARNING:
                case IMessage.INFO:
                    log.info message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.DEBUG:
                    log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Here is my manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:packageName="com.joiedurythme"
          package="com.joiedurythme">

    <application
            android:packageName="com.joiedurythme"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" android:required="true"/>

</manifest>
```

This happened when I tried to use aop on my project with [this link](https://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/). The project worked perfectly before that.

Comment: Can you delete `android:packageName="com.joiedurythme"` from your android manifest root and see the result?

Comment: did you copy other project files to your existing project

Comment: Did you clean the application and then build again?

Comment: Salman i had it after i had the problem.

Comment: Reaz no i Will try that